# Iterate through node text content with java DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom

Let's say I have an XML file that looks like this (whitespace added for clarity):

```
<stuff>
    text1
    <tag1 attribute1="value1">
        text2
    </tag1>
    text3
    <tag2 attribute2="value2">
        text4
        <tag3 attribute3="value3">
            text5
        </tag3>
        text6
    </tag2>
    text7
</stuff>
```

Using the java DOM parser, I can get the text by calling the `getTextContent()` method on the `Element` corresponding to the `stuff` tag pair. This will yield the string:

```
 text1 + text2 + text3 + text4 + text5 + text6 + text7
```

But what I'd actually like is iterate through the text parts and perform an appropriate operation on each based on which tag pairs it's surrounded by and so on, so what I'd end up with is something like

```
text1 + f(tag1, attribute1, value1, text2) + text3 + f(tag2, attribute2, value2, text4 +
f(tag3, attribute3, value3, text5) + text6) + text7
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: while only the tag pairs and their content count as `Element`, each text part is a `Node` (which is a superinterface of `Element`), and the node method `getChildNodes()` returns a `NodeList` which contains all nodes in correct order. `node instanceof Element` can be used to see which nodes are tag pairs, and `getTagName()`, `getAttribute(String name)` and `getAttributes()` can be used to retrieve the tag info. The non-`Element` nodes also have a `getTextContent()` method.